# Multiple Replacements for one Identifer

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to replace the same identifier with different replacements?

I tried

```cpp
#define M a
#define REPLACE_WITH_a(X) X
#undef M

#define M b
#define REPLACE_WITH_b(X) X
#undef M

#define FOO(X) REPLACE_WITH_a(X) REPLACE_WITH_b(X)

//FOO(M) evaluates to M M instead of a b
```

but M doesn't get replaced with either a or b

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this technique?

Comment: I want to use M as delimiter for arguments instead of comma, so I can do stuff for every argument. Another solution would be to use recursive macros but this solution requires knowledge of the maximum amount of possible arguments. Because i want to Apply two different macros to the same list of arguments I can't just define M once globally.

Comment: Your question is confusing; try to describe the problem you're trying to solve more clearly, instead of the approach at solving it.  It's hard to ease out what you're trying to do here.  Might I suggest example macro invocations with expectations on what they should expand to or something?